# how to disable autocomplete search on wpLink?

Tags: search, autocomplete

how to disable autocomplete search on wpLink?

[image: autocomplete search]

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to do this?

Comment: hi, because i use wp_editor in the front end, i don't want show autocomplete search to register user.

Comment: i have try add this code but it doesn't work for me, my site go blank.  https://www.uebbi.com/wordpress-disable-autocomplete-on-wplink/

Comment: update: problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP linked it in a comment above, but here's the code used.

**Note** This doesn't actually disable autocomplete, it simply removes all of the results before they're displayed (and I added some CSS to hide the loading icon). They're still fetched by WP, just overridden with an empty array.

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_query', 'remove_results_from_link_builder_autocomplete', 10, 2 );
function remove_results_from_link_builder_autocomplete( $results, $query ) {
    return array();
}
```

You'll also likely want some CSS to hide the autocomplete loading icon:

```
input[type=email].ui-autocomplete-loading,
input[type=text].ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background-image: none;
}
```

If you're also removing this functionality in the Link Builder popup editor (after you click the gear icon), here's some additional CSS to hide the whole search section.

```
#wplink-link-existing-content,
#search-panel {
    display: none;
}
#wp-link-wrap {
     height: 225px;
}
```